# Filling array on GPU

Tags: cuda

I want to fill my array on GPU. Order to do that i wrote generateVetor function

```
int rand_from_0_to_100_gen(void) {
    return rand() % 100;
}

__device__ void generateVector(int * hData,int count) {

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        hData[i] = rand_from_0_to_100_gen();
    }
}
```

In main i dynamically allocate memory for the array A

```
int *A = NULL;
err = cudaMalloc((void **) &A, numOfData);

generateVector(A,numOfData);
```

But function gives the error that: Calling a **host** function from **device** is not allowed. Why? What i get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 3 problems:

1. `__device__` indicates a function that is callable from GPU code not host code.  But you are calling `generateVector()` from the host.  You can fix this simply by removing the `__device__` decorator.
2. You are using `numOfData` as the size of the data to allocate.  But the required size parameter is in *bytes*.  Based on your usage of `numOfData` in your call to `generateVector()`, you should be using something like `sizeof(int)*numOfData` for the size of allocation.
3. You are passing to `generateVector()` the pointer `A`, but `A` is a pointer that points to device memory.  You cannot use these pointers directly in host code (except as parameters to API functions like cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy). Instead you will need to do something like:

   ```
   int *A = NULL;
   int *h_A = NULL;
   h_A = (int *)malloc(numOfData*sizeof(int));
   generateVector(h_A, numOfData);
   cudaMemcpy(A, h_A, numOfData*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ```

You may want to read more about how to indicate host and device functions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-type-qualifiers).

If you actually do want to use `generateVector()` from device code (somewhere else in your program) then you will have an additional problem in that the `rand()` function from `stdlib.h` is not callable from device code.  This does not seem to be your intent, however.

Comment: The question is that: i dont want to copy from host device. I directly fill my array on GPU. Do i have to copy from CPU? Is this restriction?

Comment: You cannot directly write to GPU (device) memory from host code.  You must use an API call like `cudaMemcpy` or `cudaMemset`.  Alternatively, you can launch a kernel and have it do whatever you want, from the GPU side.  But the code you've posted is host code (mostly) and does not include any kernel launches.

Answer (score 0):

Your generateVector function is marked as a *device* function, but it calls rand_from_0_to_100_gen() which calls rand(), which are not marked as device functions. GPU functions can only call code that resides on the GPU, not on the host.

My guess is this is what your error message "Calling a host function from a device function is not allowed" is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that is doing what you intend to do, even if it may not be optimal:

```
// Compiled using nvcc main.cu -arch=sm_21 -o main && ./main
// See document http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/CURAND_Library.pdf
// And http://aresio.blogspot.fr/2011/05/cuda-random-numbers-inside-kernels.html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <curand.h>

#define cuda_DBG(x) if(x!=cudaSuccess) {\
        printf("error at %s:%u\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
        return -1;\
        }

__global__ void setup_kernel(curandState *state, unsigned long seed ) {
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    curand_init( seed, id, 0, &state[id] );
} 

__global__ void generateVector(int *hData, curandState *globalState) {
    size_t i = blockIdx.x;
    float RANDOM = 100*curand_uniform( &globalState[i] );
    hData[i] = (int)RANDOM;
    if(i==50) printf("hData[50]=%u (RANDOM=%f)\n", hData[i], RANDOM);
}

int main() {
    int *A = NULL, numOfData=1000;
    curandState *devState;
    cuda_DBG(cudaMalloc((void **) &A, sizeof(int)*numOfData));
    cuda_DBG(cudaMalloc((void **) &devState, sizeof(devState)*numOfData));

    setup_kernel<<<numOfData, 1>>>(devState, time(NULL));
    generateVector<<<numOfData, 1>>>(A, devState);

    cuda_DBG(cudaFree(A));
    cuda_DBG(cudaFree(devState));
}
```